# I have to write a code where if I put a 3 digit number in, it will count how many hundreds, tens and ones are in it e.g 327=3 hunders, 2 tens. 7. ones

Tags: python

```
num = int(input('Give me a 3 digit number! :'))

div1 = 100
div2 = 110
div3 = 36

hundreds = num // div1
tens = num // div2
ones = num // div3

print("In %d there are %d hundred(s) %d ten(s) and %d ones are found" % (num, hundreds, tens, ones))
```

Output (It should be; "In 187 there are 1 hundred(s) 8 ten(s) and 7 ones are found")

> The real results

```
Give me a 3 digit number! : 187
In 187 there are 1 hundred(s) 1 ten(s) and 5 ones are found
```

Comment: Where do `110` and `36` come from? What do they have to do with the number of 10's and 1's?

Comment: just from trying after hours of not getting the math done.

Comment: @Shoze there is no need for any maths, just access to the string positions by order, I have added an answer if you want

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Yes I saw it and it was very helpful and in the future I will use it that solution but more but since I started learning a month ago. I am still very new and unfamiliar with many codes other than the most beginner ones.

Comment: @Shoze, sure no proble, good luck with learning, I also learned everything by myself on internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulus operator:

```
num = int(input('Give me a 3 digit number! :'))

hundreds = num // 100
tens = num % 100 // 10
ones = num % 10

print("In %d there are %d hundred(s) %d ten(s) and %d ones are found" % (num, hundreds, tens, ones))
```

Result:

```
Give me a 3 digit number! :187
In 187 there are 1 hundred(s) 8 ten(s) and 7 ones are found
```

Comment: There is also the divmod() function

Comment: Thank you so much! I was overcomplicating my lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply work with the string, there is no need of calculations, only index the string by order

```
num = input('Give me a 3 digit number! :')
assert num.isnumeric() and len(num) == 3 # this line verify that the input is a integer and has 3 digits
print(f"In {num} there are {num[0]} hundred(s) {num[1]} ten(s) and {num[2]} ones are found")
```

```
Give me a 3 digit number! :456
In 456 there are 4 hundred(s) 5 ten(s) and 6 ones are found
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself bored while waiting for a delivery.  I passed the time building a general solution to this problem:

```
labels = [(10, 'one'), (10, 'ten'),
          (10, 'hundred'), (1000, 'thousand'),
          (1000, 'million'), (1000, 'billion')]

def write_it_out(num):
    p = 0
    parts = []
    while num > 0 and p < len(labels):
        num, m = divmod(num, labels[p][0])
        parts.append((m, labels[p][1]))
        p += 1

    r = ""
    for part in parts[-1::-1]:
        if not part[0]:
            continue
        if r:
            r += ", "
        r += f"{part[0]} {part[1]}{'s' if part[0] > 1 else ''}"
    return r

# num = int(input('Give me a 3 digit number! :'))
# print(write_it_out(num))

def test(num):
    print(f"{num}: {write_it_out(num)}")

test(187)

test(1)
test(2)
test(440)
test(19)
test(121)
test(121003)
test(1234)
test(123456789)
test(12345678900)
test(1000000000)
```

Result:

```
187: 1 hundred, 8 tens, 7 ones
1: 1 one
2: 2 ones
440: 4 hundreds, 4 tens
19: 1 ten, 9 ones
121: 1 hundred, 2 tens, 1 one
121003: 121 thousands, 3 ones
1234: 1 thousand, 2 hundreds, 3 tens, 4 ones
123456789: 123 millions, 456 thousands, 7 hundreds, 8 tens, 9 ones
12345678900: 12 billions, 345 millions, 678 thousands, 9 hundreds
1000000000: 1 billion
```

It will mess up if you give it a negative number or a number of 1000 billion or greater.  Fixing that by adding more labels is left to the reader.

PS: Thanks @Sterling for pointing me to `divmod`!